# Gradle task assembleDebug failed when running flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1474)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1482)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1320)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1282)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:709)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:186)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This exception error is showing when the Flutter application is running.

Answer (score 0):

checkout your gradle version in the `PROJECT/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. if the `distributionUrl` contains `8.6`, change it into `8.5`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps you can try to resolve this issue:

1. Clean Project:
   Run the following commands in your project directory to clean the project and rebuild it:

   ```
   flutter clean
   flutter pub get
   flutter run
   ```
2. Check Gradle Version:
   Make sure you are using a compatible version of Gradle. Flutter often works best with a specific version. You can specify the Gradle version in the `android/build.gradle` file:

   ```
   gradle
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5'
   }
   ```
3. Check Flutter Doctor:
   Run flutter doctor to check for any additional issues or suggestions. It may provide guidance on what needs to be fixed.
4. Update Flutter:
   Make sure you are using the latest version of Flutter. Run flutter upgrade to update Flutter to the latest stable version.

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering seems to be related to an issue with Gradle's dependency resolution or corruption of the Gradle wrapper's distribution file.

```
Delete the gradle folder in your Flutter project directory

flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
```

upgrade flutter

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score -2):

The Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 error in Flutter can occur due to various reasons such as issues with AndroidX compatibility, incorrect Gradle version, network problems, or corrupted Gradle files. Here are several approaches to resolve the issue:

1. Ensure AndroidX Compatibility: If your project uses Firebase plugins
   that require AndroidX, ensure your project is migrated to AndroidX.
   Update gradle.properties with the following lines:

   **android.useAndroidX=true**

   **android.enableJetifier=true**

Then, refactor your project to AndroidX through Android Studio

2. Upgrade Flutter Packages: Sometimes, simply upgrading the Flutter
   packages can solve the problem. Run:

   **flutter pub upgrade**
3. Update Gradle Version: Check the gradle-wrapper.properties file and
   ensure the distribution URL points to the correct Gradle version.
   Also, verify that the build.gradle file specifies the correct Gradle
   plugin version
4. Clean Project and Clear Cache: Delete .gradle and .m2 directories
   from your home directory and within your project. Then, run the
   following commands:

   **flutter doctor**

   **flutter clean**

   **flutter packages**

   **pub cache clean**
5. Check Network Conditions: Ensure you have a stable internet
   connection since Gradle needs to download dependencies during the
   build process
6. Avoid Special Characters in Path: If your project path contains
   special characters, it may cause issues. Move your project to a path
   without special characters.
7. Correct Android Home Path: Ensure that the ANDROID_HOME environment
   variable is set correctly on Windows. An incorrect path can lead to
   build failures.
8. Review Verbose Logs: Run flutter run --verbose to get detailed logs
   that can help identify the specific cause of the failure.
9. Invalidate Caches in Android Studio: Go to **File > Invalidate Caches
   / Restart**... in Android Studio to clear the IDE's internal cache,
   which might be causing issues.

Try these solutions one by one, checking if the error is resolved after each step. If none of these solutions works, consider providing the verbose logs (**flutter run --verbose**) for further analysis.

Comment: [flutter run --verbose showing this](https://anotepad.com/notes/hjeyjhj9)